# Create an installer with wizard

Tags: software-installation

I have gone through following links before asking this

http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
http://www.installjammer.com/

what i need is to create an installer like vmware .
i have created an sh file which installs php,mysql and does what i need but i have to make it executable and run it.  so i need a wizard that prompts for sudo password and runs the command written in the script.

i need something that executes on any linux based platforms without making it executable via terminal.

Comment: You may want to look into the [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/). It generates standalone executable files that end users can run.

Comment: This site is specifically about Ubuntu, so you may be better off asking at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), since it's a broader audience.